# I don't understand this part of the proof

Tags: real-analysis

The proof in question is in the book "Elementary Real and Complex Analysis" by George E. Shilov.

Proof: http://prntscr.com/na1yyu

I understand the part before it and the part after it, but that highlighted part I don't. Like, why is it even necessary and why the condition of q > n?

Comment: Links to a button not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You start with rewriting $x^n=\frac{1}{x^q}$ using $n=-q$ and then since You assume $m>0$ and $q-m>0$ in this part (that's the reason for this condition) of the prove You can use $x^mx^{q-m}=x^{m+(q-m)}=x^q$ because You already proved this statement for positive exponents, and so
$$x^mx^n=x^m\frac{1}{x^mx^{q-m}}=\frac{1}{x^{q-m}}=x^{m-q}=x^{m+n}$$
using $n=-q$ again.